# How to open a text file with Python GUI?

Tags: python, file, user-interface, text, tkinter

I am trying to open a text file with Python GUI, but I  don't know how to open the text file in the GUI, I only know how to open the text file in the Python Shell. I want to open the file to the people read the text file. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Start off by surfing the net as to how to use tkinter. Try to write some code. Once you try, if you get any doubts post it here. We will try to help you then. **SO is not a code writing service**. All the best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The open() function works the same whether or not you also use tkinter. The difference is how you ask a user for a filename, if that is necessary.  (And if the filename is either hard-coded or retrieved from sys.argv, it will not be.) In 3.x, you might use

```
fname = input("File name? ")  # raw_input in 2.x
```

With tkinter

```
from tkinter.filename import askopenfilename as ask
fname = ask()  # you might want to pass a beginning directory
```

With tkinter, you can combine the ask and open steps with

```
from tkinter.filename import askopenfile as ask
ofile = ask()  # you might want to pass a beginning directory
```

but you will then not know what filename the user gave, which you might want to know so it can be saved.